# Translate model nested attribute validation message

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activemodel, rails-i18n

I have a nested attribute on which I perform presence validation. I am trying without success to provide translations for the attribute name that is returned in the full error message text.

The model is called `Identity` and contains an attribute called `identity` The model is nested within another with a `has_many` relationship.

A typical error message is currently returned like this

```
Identities identity can't be blank
```

I want to translate the attribute (by default `Identities identity`) into something else.

I have

```
en:
  activerecord:
    models:
      identity:
        identity: "whatever"
```

If I do this, I get an error

```
I18n::InvalidPluralizationData (translation data {:identity=>"whatever"} can not be used with :count => 1):
```

I have tried to add pluralisation data to this by altering the above to

```
en:
  activerecord:
    models:
      identity:
        identity:
          one: "one"
          other: "other"
```

This changes the error to

```
I18n::InvalidPluralizationData (translation data {:identity=>{:one=>"one", :other=>"other"}} can not be used with :count => 1):
```

I have also tried `many` instead of `other` without difference.

I have spent a few hours trying to make this work, having read other questions on Stack Overflow and elsewhere, without success. What is the correct way to write translations for attribute names ?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Adding some debugging output to the `human_attribute_name` method reveals what the i18n path should be.

The example has a `user` model with a `has_many :identities` relationship. The desired attribute is `identity`, an attribute of the `Identity` model, of which the `User` model *has many*.

I looked in `gems/activemodel-4.0.1/lib/active_model`, file `translation.rb`. The `human_attribute_name` method looks up the following path:

```
:"activerecord.attributes.user/identities.identity"
```

It also specifies the following as *defaults*, which are fallback translations:

```
:"activerecord.attributes.user/identities.identity"
:"activerecord.attributes.identities.identity"
:"attributes.identity"
"Identities identity"
"Identity"
```

the last two are strings, the first will match if none of the paths represented as symbols match available translations. So, in the case of no translations, the output will be the string "Identities identity" (the other string, "Identity" will never be used).

So, any of the following translation paths will work:

```
activerecord.attributes.user/identities.identity
activerecord.attributes.identities.identity
attributes.identity
```

The paths are tried in that order and the first to match is the one that will be used.

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
en:
  activerecord:
    errors:
      models:
        identity:
          attributes:
            identity:
              blank: 'Your new error message here'
```

Comment: That translates the error message ok, but I want to translate the attribute name.

Answer (score -1):

You can just provide translated values in front of db attribute names.

```
en:
  activerecord:
    attributes:
      identity: # this is model name
        identity: "translated attribute name"
```

You may want to read more about active model [attribute localization](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html#translations-for-active-record-models)

Comment: are you sure? I get `can not load translations from ...: #<Psych::SyntaxError: (...): did not find expected key while parsing a block mapping at line 126 column 13>`. I don't think that's valid yaml.

Comment: doesn't work for me. I tried in rails console `I18n.t 'activerecord.errors.attributes.identity.identity'` and that returns the expected value (so my yml is correct) but the attribute isn't translating in the error message :(

Comment: `activerecord.attributes.identity.identity` doesn't work either. After hacking the activemodel code to see what it's doing, I discovered that the requied yml is `activerecord.attributes.identities.identity`. I will provide more detail in an answer.